# TransactionScope in .NET application

Tags: .net, scope, transactions

I have written a code block to do database transaction in SQL Server database. I am using TransactionScope class to rollback all the changes if any failures during the execution. 
If I run the application in a system which running SQL SERVER, I have no problem.
If I run the application in a system and the SQL SERVER is running in another system, I am receiving an error that is MSDTC is disabled.

If I enable the MSDTC in DBServer running system, my application is working fine.

If I have to user ORACLE db, how the system will work? Should I configure something on the ORACLE DB Server to enable transaction scope? Please help me.

Thanks,
P.Gopalakrishnan.

Answer (score 1):

TransactionScope, while conceptually simple, hides a lot of magic behind the scenes.  It enables you to use one transaction that's distributed over several machines.  To do so, it needs complex support from the database - and the overhead may or may not be high.

A simpler more limited piece of technology, may suffice for you:  DbTransaction.  Your Db provider can implement a transaction with semantics similar to sql's `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION`: in short, a transaction that spans only a single connection on a single machine.

Your code would then look something like...

```
DbCommand cmd = ...;
using (DbTransaction trans = Connection.BeginTransaction()) {
  cmd.Transaction = trans; //sometimes optional, though MS-SQL requires it.

  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  [...other db commands with the same connection and transaction...]
  trans.Commit();
}
```

To be crystal clear: you can use several other connections while the transaction is open - but there's no link between them.  Commands executed on different connections aren't rolled back on transaction abort (much like arbitrary C# code won't be rolled back on transaction abort).

This approach is lighter weight, more finely grained, and works for a broader range of database providers, and it doesn't require the MSDTC to boot.  On the flip side, transactions are connection-specific (if you have several connections, they don't share the transaction), they can't be distributed, and you'll need to manually enlist commands into the transaction (at least for MS-SQL).

Note, if you fail to enlist a command in a transaction, MS-SQL will throw an exception, SQLite will implicitly enroll the command nevertheless, and I'm not sure what oracle does.  Since all commands *must* be enrolled in the transactions anyhow, this is just an unhandily redundant API, but it's not terribly problematic.

Answer (score 0):

TransactionScope supports (hybrid) fast local transactions with the option to promote them to more expensive distributed transactions, when ever required. For distributed transactions, MSDTC is required.

A reason for promoting to distributed transactions is if you involve a second database in the same TransactionScope.

Oracle Data Provider version 10.2.0.3 and higher do support local transactions + distributed transactions (same as for SQL Server 2005 and higher). Older versions of ODP.NET only support distributed transactions.